# How to disable automatic Thunderbird updates?

Tags: thunderbird, automatic-update

As with the current version of Thunderbird (91.x), it is not possible to disable automatic updates via Preferences:
[image]

Is it possible to do this via Config Editor, and if yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're on Windows, so you can [disable Thunderbird updates via the registry.](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1314978)

Easiest way is to make a new text file with the following contents:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Mozilla\Thunderbird]
"DisableAppUpdate"=dword:00000001
```

Then rename it with a .reg extension (like `Disable Thunderbird Updates.reg`) and run it.

If you've already been upgraded beyond the version you want (such as to the atrocious "Supernova" v115) and would like to go back, you can!  Just [install the old version](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/thunderbird/releases/102.15.1/win64/en-US/) and add `-allow-downgrade` to your Thunderbird shortcut so you don't have to reset your profile.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about changing this behaviour via the Config Editor --`app.update.auto` is not in my version of Thunderbird, and `app.update.auto.migrated` is always recreated and set to `true` if I try to remove it-- but would a `policies.json` file work? I'm not sure if Thunderbird also respects `policies.json` like Firefox does, but that might be an option. Specifically, there are some pre-built [policy templates](https://github.com/mozilla/policy-templates) with instructions on install/configuration:

> Policies can be specified using the Group Policy templates on Windows, Intune on Windows, configuration profiles on macOS, or by creating a file called policies.json. On Windows, create a directory called distribution where the EXE is located and place the file there. On Mac, the file goes into Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/distribution. On Linux, the file goes into firefox/distribution, where firefox is the installation directory for firefox, which varies by distribution or you can specify system-wide policy by placing the file in /etc/firefox/policies.

Some applicable ones might be:

- [DisableAppUpdate](https://github.com/mozilla/policy-templates#disableappupdate) : "Turn off application updates within Firefox."
- [ManualAppUpdateOnly](https://github.com/mozilla/policy-templates#manualappupdateonly) : "Allow manual updates only and do not notify the user about updates.."

And a sample `policies.json` might look like:

```
{
  "policies": {
    "ManualAppUpdateOnly": true
  }
}
```

---

For what it's worth, that particular policy is referenced in Thunderbird's source code here:

https://github.com/mozilla/releases-comm-central/blob/925606caac04e4b8b401807fd631ac83c9e7b52d/mail/components/enterprisepolicies/Policies.jsm#L875

```
ManualAppUpdateOnly: {
  onBeforeAddons(manager, param) {
    if (param) {
      manager.disallowFeature("autoAppUpdateChecking");
    }
  },
},
```

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OS X one might:

1. Edit
   `/Applications/Thunderbird.app/Contents/Resources/update-settings.ini`

   f.e. prepend a hash (`#`) at line
   `ACCEPTED_MAR_CHANNEL_IDS=thunderbird-comm-release`
2. Or rename `/Applications/Thunderbird.app/Contents/MacOS/Thunderbird Software Update.app` to something different.